# Meteor: Http Call return Undefined on response after an Http Response

Tags: javascript, php, meteor, meteor-react

I try to upload a file by encoding the content as base64 using a meteor app and a custom php script.

The php script is the following:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\ListBlobsOptions;

error_log("Method:".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],0);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS'){
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
  error_log("Options Called",0);
  die();
} else {
  error_log("Post Called",0);

  function create_storage_connection()
  {
      return "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=".getenv('AZURE_ACCOUNT').";AccountKey=".getenv('AZURE_KEY');
  }

  $connectionString=create_storage_connection();
  $blobRestProxy= ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
  $container_name=getenv('AZURE_CONTAINER');

  $data=file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data=json_decode($data,true);
  try{
    //Upload data
    $file_data=base64_decode($data['data']);
    $data['name']=uniqid().$data['name'];
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob($container_name,$data['name'],$file_data);
    $blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob($container_name, $data['name']);

    //Download url info
    $listBlobsOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
    $listBlobsOptions->setPrefix($data['name']);
    $blob_list = $blobRestProxy->listBlobs($container_name, $listBlobsOptions);
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    $url=[];
    foreach($blobs as $blob)
    {
      $urls[]=$blob->getUrl();
    }
    error_log("Urls:\n".implode(" , ",$urls),0);
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $result=json_encode(['files'=>"sent",'url'=>$urls]);
    error_log("Result: ".$result,0);
    echo $result;
  } catch(ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();

    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode(['code'=>$code,'message'=>$error_message]);

  }

}
```

And on my meteor script I created a file named "imports/ui/File.jsx" having the following content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FileUpload} from '../api/FileUpload.js';

class File extends Component {

  changeFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let files = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
    var file = files.files[0];

    var reader=new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() {
      Meteor.call('fileStorage.uploadFile',reader.result,file.name,file.type)
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.changeFile.bind(this) }>
        <label>
          <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="file" />
        </label>

        <button type="submit">UploadFile</button>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

export default File;
```

And I also have a file named `imports/api/FileUpload.js` that handles the http call to the server:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

export default Meteor.methods({
  'fileStorage.uploadFile'(base64Data,name,mime) {
      // this.unblock();
      let http_obj={
        'data':{
          'data':base64Data,
          'name':name,
          'mime':mime
        },
      }

      HTTP.call("POST","http://localhost/base64Upload/",http_obj,function(err,response){
        console.log("Response:",response);
      });
  }
});
```

The problem is even though I get I successfull response from my server the:

```
        console.log("Response:",response);
```

Does not print the returned json response from my server script to the console. Instead I get the following message (in my browser console):

> Response: undefined

I cannot uinderstand why I get undefined on response even though the php script returns a response. Also if I `console.log` the err I get the following:

> Error Error: network
>   Καταγραφή στοίβας:
>   httpcall_client.js/HTTP.call/xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:3000/packages/http.js?hash=d7408e6ea3934d8d6dd9f1b49eab82ac9f6d8340:244:20

And I cannot figure out why does it happen.

## Edit 1:

The meteor App does 2 Http calls 1 using `OPTIONS` method and one that uses `POST`

As requested when replaced the `die()` with:

```
  var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']); exit;
```

I get the response:

> /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/base64Upload/src/public/index.php:14:string 'OPTIONS' *(length=7)*

Also on my network tab of the browser it says:

[image: The http calls on network tab]

Please keep in mind that the meteor performs 2 http calls to the script one using http `OPTIONS` method and one that uses the  http `POST` one. What I want to get is the one that uses the http `POST` one.

## Edit 2:

I also tried to put a timeout of 2 seconds by changing the `http_obj` into:

```
let http_obj={
        'data':{
          'data':base64Data,
          'name':name,
          'mime':mime
        },
        'timeout':2000
      }
```

But I get the following error:

> Error Error: Can't set timers inside simulations

Comment: Have you've check the [Preview] tab on your [Network] option when you've check your given response?

Comment: yes for some reason I do not get response either in the response tab.

Comment: Do you think its because you've called `die()` in your `if` condition? What value did you get when you `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']); exit;`?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I needed to make the method to run on server:

I did it by changing the `imports/api/FileUpload.js` into this: (I also removed unwanted code)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

export const UploadedFile=null;

if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    'fileStorage.uploadFile'(base64Data,name,mime) {
        // this.unblock();
        let http_obj={
          'data':{
            'data':base64Data,
            'name':name,
            'mime':mime
          },
          // 'timeout':2000,
          'headers':{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }

        return HTTP.call("POST","http://localhost/base64Upload/",http_obj);
    }
  });
}
```

And putting this require into `server/main.js` resulting into this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {FileUpload} from '../imports/api/FileUpload.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

Also on `imports/ui/File.jsx` I call the method like that:

```
Meteor.call('fileStorage.uploadFile',reader.result,file.name,file.type,function(err,response){
        console.log(response);
      })
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, I am having similar issues with my HTTP.call() do you think you could kindly have a look at it. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065295/how-do-i-modify-my-http-call-so-that-it-returns-relevant-information?noredirect=1#comment77118740_45065295